# Android @layout/list_item not resolved into its int value

Tags: android, android-custom-attributes

I would like to create a custom linear layout (to work as some basic list) which accepts a custom parameter from xml, like this:

```
<MyLinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
myns:layout_to_inflate="@layout/list_item"/>
```

Then, use it in the constructor:

```
String layoutToInflate = attrs.getAttributeValue(NAMESPACE, "layout_to_inflate");
```

I get "@layout/list_item". It is not resolved by the system into the int value which is accessible in R.layout.list_item.

Sure I can parse it and use Resources.getIdentifier to look up the ID, then inflate it, but I think that is not the way.

Then... what is the way? Can I get the system to resolve it directly into the int?

UPDATE:

list_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Text here!" />
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myns="http://com.example.layoutinflate"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.layoutinflate.MyLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    myns:layout_to_inflate="@layout/list_item" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Contents MyLinearLayout.java:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = MyLinearLayout.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyLinearLayout);

        int layoutId = styledAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyLinearLayout_layout_to_inflate, -1);
        int layoutIdInt = styledAttributes.getInt(R.styleable.MyLinearLayout_layout_to_inflate, -1);
        String str = styledAttributes.getString(R.styleable.MyLinearLayout_layout_to_inflate);

        Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(layoutId) + ";" + str + ";" + layoutIdInt); //-1; null; -1

        styledAttributes.recycle();

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I got a very nice -1....
I suppose I got it because of not googling and not using attrs.xml... 
I googled and read a lot about this topic, but with attrs.xml it didn't work, neither got the string "@layout/list_item"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly define this custom attribute inside your `attrs.xml`. It has to be like this:

```
<attr name="layout_to_inflate" format="reference" />
<declare-styleable name="MyLinearLayout">
    <attr name="layout_to_inflate" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then you can get this value inside your `MyLinearLayout` object with this:

```
int layoutToInflateId = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyLinearLayout_layout_to_inflate, R.layout.<default_layout_to_inflate>);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this before, but I always got the default value...
   TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyLinearLayout);
attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyLinearLayout_layout_to_inflate, R.layout.<default_layout_to_inflate>); 
returns the default.